# Detect tab restore event

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that needs to distinguish between when a new tab is created (e.g. Ctrl+T or Open link in new tab) and when a recently-closed tab is restored (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+T or Recently closed). All of these actions trigger [chrome.tabs.onCreated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated), but none of the properties in the tab parameter tell me whether this is a new tab or a restored tab. I was hoping that the [commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) would allow me to detect when Ctrl+Shift+T is pressed to restore a closed tab, but it seems it's only for overwriting shortcuts and usable for detecting window management keypresses.

Currently I'm checking `tab.pendingUrl !== "chrome://newtab/"`, but this treats opening a link in a new tab as though it was restoring a tab, which is not the correct behavior. Is there any way a Chrome extension can detect whether a tab is being newly created or restored?

Comment: Looks like you can check for `tab.pendingUrl && tab.pendingUrl !== tab.url`

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm. It's `false` for restored tabs and `true` for new tabs. I don't think it's even necessary to check `tab.pendingUrl` first. If you want to make that into an answer I'll accept it.